# How is the main process running after return in PHP and Shell

Tags: php, linux, bash, daemon

I am new to daemons and shell script. 
I have followed a [tutorial](http://collaboradev.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/#codesyntax_3) to run a PHP file as a service.

Here is the code. I did `chmod a+x` on both the `/etc/init.d/daemon` and the `/home/user/Work/Daemon.php` files.

Here is the code of the bash file `daemon`. The problem that I am facing is that, when I do a `sudo service daemon start`, it just prints `Starting Program Name:` and does not close it(i.e. I have to do a ctrl+c to close it). When I check the log that the PHP file it printing, it does show that the PHP file was running when the command was given.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   /etc/init.d/Daemon
#
# Starts the at daemon
#
# chkconfig: 345 95 5
# description: Runs the demonstration daemon.
# processname: Daemon

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

#startup values
log=/var/log/Daemon.log

#verify that the executable exists
test -x /home/user/Work/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0

#
#   Set prog, proc and bin variables.
#
prog="Program Name"
proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon
bin=/home/user/Work/Daemon.php

start() {
    # Check if Daemon is already running
    if [ ! -f $proc ]; then
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon $bin --log=$log
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $proc
        echo
    fi

    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $bin
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $proc
    echo
        return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}   

reload() {
    restart
}   

status_at() {
    status $bin
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
reload|restart)
    restart
    ;;
condrestart)
        if [ -f $proc ]; then
            restart
        fi
        ;;
status)
    status_at
    ;;
*)

echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
exit $RETVAL
```

And here is the code of Daemon.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

while(true){
    file_put_contents('/var/log/Daemon.log', 'Running...', FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(1);
}//end while

?>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the PHP file to the following code, and it stared working. The daemon was expecting a return. But I don't understand why it goes to the main process block in PHP after the `return`. Could someone please explain it?

New Code.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

$log = '/var/log/vb_q.log';

//fork the process to work in a daemonized environment
file_put_contents($log, "Status: starting up.n", FILE_APPEND);
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if($pid == -1){
    file_put_contents($log, "Error: could not daemonize process.n", FILE_APPEND);
    return 1; //error
}
else if($pid){
    return 0; //success
}
else{
   //the main process
   while(true){
       file_put_contents($log, 'Running...', FILE_APPEND);
       sleep(1);
   }//end while
}//end if 
?>
```

Comment: That should not be needed because i did a `chmod a+x Daemon.php` which makes it an executable without the need of a `php Daemon.php`. But, still let me give it a try.

Comment: In your main process `echo $pid;`... this should give you the answer why it ends up there.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand why it goes to the main process block in PHP
>   after the `return`. Could someone please explain it?

It does not go to the main process block after the `return`. The `$pid = pcntl_fork()` creates a child process; now there are two processes executing this same code:

- the parent, where `$pid` is the ID of the child process, executes the block

  ```
  else if($pid){
      return 0; //success
  }
  ```

  and after the `return` the `Daemon.php` program terminates (which causes your shell script's `start()` function to resume)
- the child, where `$pid` is 0, executes the block you call *main process*

  ```
  else{
     //the main process
     while(true){
         file_put_contents($log, 'Running...', FILE_APPEND);
         sleep(1);
     }//end while
  }//end if
  ```

  where it did not go after a `return`, but just thru the `if` … `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a running user to your daemon so that it runs with appropriate privileges instead of `root`.

Additionally move your `touch $proc` above the daemon start. To ensure it is able to create the lock file prior to starting the daemon.

The stop command looks identical to mine.

eg:

```
start(){
        if [ ! -f $proc ]; then
        echo -n "Starting $prog: "
        touch $proc
        daemon --user=apache --log=$log $bin
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && rm $proc
        echo
        else
        echo -n "$prog is already running"
        echo
    fi

    return $RETVAL  

}
```

Also you can test your lock file to ensure you are able to access it.

```
. /etc/init.d/functions

#startup values
log=/var/log/Daemon.log
prog="Program Name"
proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon
bin=/home/user/Work/Daemon.php
if [ ! -w /var/lock/subsys ]; then
    echo -n "You do not have permissions to run this service"
    echo
    exit 0
fi
if [ ! -x $bin ]; then
    echo $bin is not executable!
    echo
    exit 0
fi
RETVAL=0
```

---

**Update**

PHP scripts are not meant to run as a normal service. 
In order to control it you have to fork it for the service to continue running and allow the parent PHP process to close the script, rather than in the current thread that called it.  See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html#RETURN_VALUE

For example launch a service - service  never returned that it started or errored, since it is in a `while` loop.

You should additionally check for your child process and ensure it is assigned as a main process (session leader), after it has been forked as well. Otherwise the calling process remains the leader.

```
if ($pid == -1) {
        return 1; //return error to service
} elseif ($pid) {
        //parent process - break out of it
        return 0;
} else {
    /* child Process - run by calling pcntl_fork */
    try {
        if (posix_setsid() < 0) {
            return; //error assigning a session id
        }
        $sid = posix_getpid(); //retrieve current process name

       //... Your Code Here
   } catch(\Exception $e) {
       return 1;
   }

}
```

See: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your bash script is running the php process alright, but it is running in the foreground and the bash script is waiting for it to end before it continues. Since the php script runs forever, try adding an ampersand after the command like this: `daemon $bin --log=$log &` to make your php process run in the background.